# How many five-digit number $ABCDE$ exist

Tags: combinatorics

How many five-digit numbers $ABCDE$  exist if,

a) $A>B>C>D>E$

or

b) $A≥B≥C≥D≥E $

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{red}{\color{red}}$
a) Consider $9876543210$. You need to choose five of these digits to make your number. There are thus ${10  \choose 5} = 252$ options.

$ $ b) Consider the 9-length string $111111111$ with 5 markers inserted, eg $\red A11\red{BC}111\red D1111\red E$. Then report ABCDE as the number of $1$s to the right of each: $97740$ in this case.

Equivalently, insert ABCDE into $9876543210$, except not in front of the initial $9$, and report ABCDE as the digit to the left in each case. The above example would be $9\red A87\red{BC}654\red D3210\red E$.

The digit marker positions can be chosen in ${14 \choose 5} = 2002$  ways. If "$00000$" is forbidden, $2001$ options remain.

Comment: Your solution for a) is nicely elegant.